# WorkManager returns result before completion of async method in it

Tags: android, android-fragments, ffmpeg, android-workmanager

I want to apply some editing on the media file before uploading and I've used FFMPEG library for that. But as FFMPEG executes the command with a callback in it. So, the WorkManager returns success even before completion of ffmpeg command completion. How can i avoid it and keep WorkManager on hold until the work is completed. I've used CountLatch as well to add wait but then ffmpeg doesn't work starts work and WorkManager remains stuck. Any ideas would be appreciable. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For adapting callbacks, you should use a ListenableWorker instead of a Worker.  You can find more information about threading options here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/threading